# How to find how many time function call happened?

Tags: magento2.4, magento-2-commerce, function

I am using cookies to avoid every time function call happens, how to check after created cookies how many times function call happened?

Comment: Javascript? PHP?

Comment: PHP file, i used cookies for saving those values, need to check after saved to cookies still how many time function call happens?

Answer (score 2):

Install the [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org) extension for PHP and enable it for your IDE or use a service like [Tideways](https://tideways.com) or [Blackfire](https://blackfire.io) which does the same on the server-side with a web UI. Xdebug is available for free, Tideways & Blackfire will cost on a monthly basis. All of those will give you a lot of detail about what is going on for each request and help to figure out where bottlenecks are.

Answer (score 1):

Via logs or debugging. You can find this in the var folder of your root directory.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Stephan Hochdoerfers answer ... there is another free profiler: https://github.com/NoiseByNorthwest/php-spx